# Calculating Average over date

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I try to calculate an average of value over time: I created a tablix in ssrs:
[image]

[image]

I used this expression in my query:

```
   Avg(case when CounterName = 'Count 1' then calculationUnits end) as Average
```

The Average which is shown in the picture:

```
=SUM(Fields!Prod.Value)/3
```

I divided the Sum of the Values by 3 (in a day there are 3 shifts) but I would like to have an average over the date.

Can I use in my query something with:

```
OVER(PARTITION BY [intervaldate])
```

I would like to divide the sum of each machines by the numbers of date value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try getting just the rows for each date in your dateset and use the SSRS functions to get the average and the sum.

To filter you query in SQL use the the parameters inside the SQL Statement. 
Your query should look something like this:

```
select
    *
from
    yourData
where
    date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

Example data for this statement:

```
yourDate               M101   M102  M103
2015-12-24 12:00:00    100    34    54
2015-12-25 12:00:00    25     67    87
2015-12-26 12:00:00    30     434   54
2015-12-27 12:00:00    140    42    65
2015-12-28 12:00:00    21     66    77
```

Now create a tablix containing the data in your SSRS report. Add two new rows outside of your detail group:

[image]

Now add expressions in the new rows, to get the sum and the average, example for M101:

for sum:

```
=Sum(Fields!M101.Value)
```

for average (over date)

```
=SUM(Fields!Prod.Value) / COUNTDISTINCT(Fields!DateValue.Value)
```

Comment: I use a parameter startdate and enddate. The user can choose the date.

Comment: That's no problem with this method, use in the where statement in the SQL "where sqldate > @Startdate and sqldate < @Enddate" to filter the dateset beforehand

Comment: could you maybe explain me it in more detail, I don´t know how I can do it in SSRS? I get the sum from the SSRS function but I don´t know how I can use the average function

Comment: thank you for your answer but unfortunately this is not the correct solution for my question. I need to divide the sum of the Machines by the numbers of dateValue,

Comment: If you have one row for one date it does exactly that

Comment: I have got more than one row for the date

Comment: try using `=Sum(Fields!M101.Value)/CountRows("YourDataset")` instead of the AVG function, it should do the trick

Comment: thanks for your help. If I use `CountRows` Function than it count me every row. I used this expression: `=SUM(Fields!Prod.Value) / COUNTDISTINCT(Fields!DateValue.Value)`  This expression gives the right average. But anyway thanks for your help

Comment: ok. no problem, i'll update my answer accordingly and will upvote your question

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see the relationship between your snippet of code and the example data.  However, the logic that you want is probably:

```
Avg(case when CounterName = 'Count 1' then calculationUnits end) as Average
```

Note that there is no `else` clause.  Without the `else` the `case` expression evaluates to `NULL`, which is ignored by `avg()`.

Your expression has `else 0`.  This is treated as a legitimate value, so non-matching rows affect the final results.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this is not the real problem in my query, I will calculate the average over the datetime.